# When subclassing UITableView how to customize cell preparation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to customize a cell in my `UITableView` subclass. But I cannot figure out is there any way to do it without defining itself `dataSource`, because it's obviously override external `dataSource`.

So basically I want to be `UITableView` `dataSource` without rewriting this property.

I have already come up with some dirty workaround. I'm reloading the `-setDataSource:` method to keep `UITableView` `dataSource` itself and save incoming data source into an internal variable for passing the requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to override `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and make your cell modifications there. The datasource will populate the cell as usual.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Calling super will let the datasource methods be called
    UITableViewCell * cell = [super cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Do whatever to the cell here
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That the method I'm looking for, after you pointed it to me, I finally found it in public header.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's does not work, `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` executed only if you invoke that method on table view instance by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your cell in one of two ways: code or interface builder. The tableview datasource is the DATA you want to show, it has nothing to do with the presentation of that data.

What do you want to customize about your tableview? Changing fonts, font colors and background colors are easy to do. If you want to add additional ui elements, like images, more labels, then the quickest way is to use Interface Builder.

Comment: I want to apply transformation, it can not be done by `IB`, but it can be done by code, that what I want to do. Please, read my question again and tell me what part is unclear for you.